# Check object's permission levels

Tags: 2010, permissions, security, security-trimming

Are there tools that will display all the permissions to an object in SharePoint 2010 Server? For example, we want to see which AD groups, SharePoint groups, and individuals have any level of access to a particular list. Is there a tool that will give us a list of who has what access to which object?

This can be free or commercial products. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, you can manually enter a user/group to see what their level of access is on a library/list.

Under The Library/List > Permissions > Check Permissions in the ribbon. From here, you'll enter a username/group.

Actually, you can see a full list of everyone's access on the Permissions page.